# .Net MVC altering view after rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

Is there a way to get access to the view as something like a serialized string after razor renders the view, just prior to it being sent back as a response to the browser?

The motivation for this question is to find a way to inject React Components by somehow altering the Razor-compiled content as a means of rendering/hydrating initial React Components on the server.

Comment: That's what Ajax is meant for.

Comment: @Robert  -  prior to it being send back as a response to the browser. Updated question for context.

Comment: http://codetunnel.io/how-to-render-an-aspnet-mvc-view-to-a-string-from-within-the-controller/

Comment: Describe what you want to achieve the by that i.e. what your aim to do so.

Comment: @SmitPatel - The second paragraph explains what I'd like to ultimately do but to expand a bit further, in the examples of isomorphic (or universal) Server Side Rendering with React that I have come across, I saw that what needed to happen was that React components with their relevant state (hydrated) needed to be injected into the DOM before the browser receives the payload. So what I'm looking for working in an 4.6x MVC framework is to hijack the View just after it's been compiled via Razor and just previous to it being sent back to the browser that requested the content.

Comment: I suspect you're thinking about it the wrong way round. What you probably want to do is have some code which creates your hydrated React components and injects them into the View (possibly even this could be done using Razor code). All the examples online seem to use NodeJS though, because basically how the React server-side stuff seems to work is that it runs a version of React on the server, and since React is a JavaScript library, Node is really the only server which can be used.

Comment: Actually, after a moment's googling out of curiosity (bear in mind I know almost nothing about React beyond the basics), it seems that perhaps you want to be using this: https://reactjs.net/ - see also the server side rendering page: https://reactjs.net/guides/server-side-rendering.html

Comment: @ADyson - Yes that's the current resource I've been referencing but this way, in essence, you're embedding react components during the Razor-compilation process. But this way leaves some things to be desired - one example of such is if we're using a react-header component in a header.cshtml file and if you're also adding a component into the body, the state for both gets a little wonky when redux kicks in on the server. Ideally, I'd want to know if there's a way to manipulate the page just after it's been Razor-compiled.